# How to make child elements stay the same during parent element transition and transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

As shown in the figure, I get the coordinates and dimensions of the element before and after the change, and use the
transform and scale to realize the change before and after, and also with transition to realize the animation effect.
But I found a problem, the child element also followed the change.

This code demonstrates an identical problem, as the principle is the same.

```css
.transform-scale {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 40px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.transform-scale:hover {
  transform: scale(3, 1);
}

.transform-scale:hover .transform-scale-kid {
  transform: scale(calc(1 / 3), 1);
}

.transform-scale .transform-scale-kid {
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: transform .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="transform-scale">
  <div class="transform-scale-kid">hover</div>
</div>
```

And I did inverse scaling on the child elements, but the result is not satisfactory.
I would like to know if there is a way to keep the child elements at their original size.

As shown in the code snippet above. How to make .transform-scale-kid keep its original size during transition

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd like to achieve can't be done with scaling, it has an effect on everything that it is applied to (inside it). The same effect without the distortion of the text, can be done like so:

```css
/*to convert the parent to a proper container:*/

.transform-scale {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*style of the child:*/

.transform-scale-kid {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 108px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  transition: width .5s;
}


/*style of the child on hover*/

.transform-scale:hover .transform-scale-kid {
  width: 325px;
}
```

```html
<div class="transform-scale">
  <div class="transform-scale-kid">hover</div>
</div>
```